# In the Flutter what is best way to add package in pubspec.yaml file?

Tags: dart, flutter

In flutter I'm little bit concussion to add package.

Rather than add package with version, is it best way to add package without version in **pubspec.yaml** file?

Might be, By default it will acquire latest version. But what happen when after adding new version will be available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can omit the version or use `any`, but it's a good idea to add a version range.

### Avoid updates breaking your app/package

Specifying a version constraint helps to avoid unexpected breaking your app by running `flutter packages get` when new dependency versions become available that contain breaking changes (are not compatible with your old code).
You can then intentionally extend the version range for a dependency when you align your code to the new version of the dependency.

Dart and packages are supposed to follow Semantic Versioning which means when an update contains a breaking change, the major version number needs to be incremented.

For versions below `1.0.0` incrementing the minor version number indicates a breaking change.

The `^` is a shortcut to define a version range that indicates the defined version and all later versions that don't contain breaking changes.

So usually you would use

```
some_dependency: ">=2.0.0 <3.0.0"
```

or short

```
some_dependency: ^2.0.0
```

If some update fixes a bug in `2.1.0` that your application or package depends on you can use

```
some_dependency: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

or short

```
some_dependency: ^2.1.0
```

### Performance

Specifying a narrow version constraint also can make `flutter packages get/upgrade` faster especially when your application contains a lot of dependencies because this reduces the search space for `packages get/upgrade` that it needs to traverse to find a compatible set of dependencies.

### Missing functionality

Please upvote https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12627 to get proper information from `flutter packages get/upgrade` when newer dependency versions are available than your constraints allow (like `pub get/upgrade` does for non-Flutter Dart projects)

### See also

- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/versioning
- [What does plus one (+1) mean in dart's dependency versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53626418/what-does-plus-one-1-mean-in-darts-dependency-versioning/53626488#53626488)

Comment: Nice explanation.. Thanks for improve our knowledge.